# Bootstrap Profile Card

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to build a profile card in Bootstrap 3 and I'm having trouble getting the image to fit into the card.  I think I can do this easier if I link to image in the css but I have many profile cards with all different people so I think keeping the image link in the HTML is better in this case.

Here's how I'd like it:

[image: http://puu.sh/ldqbm/d1d999b410.png]

and here's the where I'm at:http://jsfiddle.net/L3789n7u/1/

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

~Tony

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="people-cards">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="well">
                    <div class="profile-image">
                        <img src="https://higherlogicdownload.s3.amazonaws.com/MBGH/4f7f512a-e946-4060-9575-b27c65545cb8/UploadedImages/Board%20Photos/SIZE%20150x190/PAMELA%20HANNON%202015.jpg">
                            <div class="card-info">
                     <h3 div class="company">Company Name</h3>

                     <h4 div class="name">Person Name</h4>
                     <h5 div class="title">Job Title</h5>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I think I got it but it seems a bit bloated.  is there a more elegant way? http://www.bootply.com/COzGqZWCBY

Answer (score 0):

As ever you have multiple options, here is example of one of them.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="people-cards">
            <div class="col-md-6" style="border: 1px solid black;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="profile-image" style="float:left;">
                        <img src="https://higherlogicdownload.s3.amazonaws.com/MBGH/4f7f512a-e946-4060-9575-b27c65545cb8/UploadedImages/Board%20Photos/SIZE%20150x190/PAMELA%20HANNON%202015.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="profile-info">
                        <h3 div class="company">Company Name</h3>
                        <h4 div class="name">Person Name</h4>
                        <h5 div class="title">Job Title</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="profile-link">
                        <a href="">VIEW PROFILE</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically you need to make profile image to float left, so other content will appear next to it. Also because your example how you would like it contains border around card you need to wrap image, info and link in row. If you want to customize image size you can still use all Bootstrap's `col-size-number`.

[Working example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dejanmarolt/cvokm5hw/1/)